# Operações em linhas de um DataFrame no R

Tags: r, dplyr

Comecei a usar o R há pouco tempo. Gostaria de subtrair linhas correspondentes de um DataFrame ou seja:

[image: Dados de exemplo]

Os números da coluna ID são fixos, porem, os dados da coluna VALOR não. A ideia seria subtrair os valores atrelados aos IDs 1 e 4, 2 e 5, 3 e 6 conforme indicado na imagem da tabela. Neste caso, uma tabela de N linhas resultaria em uma nova coluna de N/2 linhas.

Se existir alguma forma de fazer isso pelo Dplyr seria fantástico.

Seguem dados que podem ser usado para reproduzir o problema.

```
set.seed(37)
dados <- tibble::tibble(id = 1:6, valor = rnorm(6, 100, 20))
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Duas formas possíveis de resolver esse problema.

Antes, vamos criar os dados:

```
set.seed(37)
library(dplyr)
dados <- tibble::tibble(id = 1:6, valor = rnorm(6, 100, 20))
```

Primeira: criar uma variável que coloque os valores que devem ser subtraídos na mesma linha para poder relacionar eles:

```
dados %>% 
  mutate(valor2 = lag(valor, nrow(dados)/2),
         dif = valor2 - valor)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      id valor valor2   dif
#>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 102.     NA  NA   
#> 2     2 108.     NA  NA   
#> 3     3 112.     NA  NA   
#> 4     4  94.1   102.  8.37
#> 5     5  83.4   108. 24.2 
#> 6     6  93.3   112. 18.2
```

Você pode adicionar `filter(!is.na(dif))` caso queira que os `NA`s não apareçam.

A segunda forma é criar uma variável que relacione os casos (chame aqui de par), e então usar o `summarise` para fazer o cálculo.

```
dados %>% 
  mutate(par = rep(seq_len(nrow(dados)/2), 2)) %>% 
  group_by(par) %>% 
  summarise(ids = paste(id, collapse = " - "),
            dif = diff(rev(valor)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>     par ids     dif
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1 1 - 4  8.37
#> 2     2 2 - 5 24.2 
#> 3     3 3 - 6 18.2
```

Comment: Fantástico . Funcionou direitinho. Meu DF tem mais de 20k linhas. A estrutura proposta ira me ajudar a afinar outros codigos que tenho.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda!